# Dummy callback interface

Tags: android, callback

In the example master-detail-flow code from Google that Eclipse creates for you, theres this stuff in the fragment:

```
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

public interface Callbacks {
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
        // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}
```

I understand how a callback interface is used to communicate from a fragment to it's containing Activity, but what is this dummy callback good for?

Comment: There is no issue really, I just wonder why they have this dummy interface, if it serves any purpose and I should use such a dummy interface in my own classes/ fragments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dummy callback is made to avoid the need for testing the validity of the callback when using it.

The other way to 'reset' the callbacks in `onDetach` is to set it to null, but that would require null testing every time it is used, which is a lot of repetitive/boring code.

Comment: Alright. But why would I have to reset the callback anyways, I would just create it in onCreate, it then lives until the fragment is being destroyed. What's wrong with that?

Comment: because after onDetach, the events may not be relevant anymore, as the fragment is not attached to an Activity. chances are your callbacks will have issue when receiving events from a detached fragment.