# OnClickListener called after fragment detach

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've some rare crash reports of a live app, with `OnClickListener` of a `Gridview` being called after the destruction of its parent fragment.

Here's a MCVE of the situation:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    private Activity activity;  

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        this.activity = null;
    }

   ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
              activity.doSomething();
           }
       }
    }
}
```

`activity.doSomething()` sometimes crashes with a NullPointerException. There's no other place where I write on `this.activity` besides `onAtach()` and `onDetach()`.

I understand that a quick fix would be just checking if the Fragment `isAdded()` or the `activity` field for null, but I want to find the reason behind this crash.

Is this a bug, or expected behaviour and I should always be checking the state of the fragment?

Comment: Better to used `Interface`

Comment: Either check for `activity` to be not null or use an Interface as mentioned above.

Comment: What do you mean by "using an Interface" in this situation?

Comment: Ok, I assume that's a reference to this pattern: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @M D , @shkschneider, I have tried to put interface in my answer, can you tell if this is correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @M D and @shkschneider mentioned above, you should use `Interface` here

I have tried to provide sample here with code :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    private Activity activity;  
    private ArrayList<DoSomethingInterface> callback = new ArrayList<DoSomethingInterface>();
    private DoSomethingInterface callback1;

    public MyFragment(DoSomethingInterface interface) {
           this.callback1 = interface;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        this.activity = null;
    }

   ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
              //activity.doSomething();
              if(callback.size() > 0) {
                  for(int i = 0; i < callback.size(); i++) {
                      callback.get(i).doSomething();
                  }
              }

              if(callback1 != null) {
                  callback1.doSomething();
              }
           }
       }
    }




public interface DoSomethingInterface {
    public void doSomething();
}

public void registerListener(DoSomethingInterface interface) {

    //this.callback = interface;
    callback.add(interface);

}

}
```

**OtherActivity.java :**

```
public OtherActivity extends Activity implements doSomethingInterface {

    private MyFragment myFragmentObject;

public void onCreate() {

    // pass reference to MyFragment using constructor
    myFragmentObject = new MyFragment(this);

    // or other way, using a method
    myFragmentObject.registerListener(this);

}

@Override
public void doSomething() {
    // callback will come
}
}
```

Comment: Sure that `interface` would work. And you still check the the `interface` (here named `callback`) for not being `null`, which was the main problem (the `interface` just being a nicer code).

Comment: I've come across this question, which contains a very elegant example of what should be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956476/dummy-callback-interface

Comment: There are two issues with this approach: #1, a fragment is supposed to have an empty constructor, so they can be re-instantiated by the runtime. #2, by adding a reference to the activity in the constructor or with the register method, you may create memory leaks. If you want to sport the interface approach here, better check whether activity is instanceof the interface in onAttach and set it, so you can clear it onDetach.

Comment: Fragment should never be initalised using constructor. FragmentManager is free to manage fragment's live and it will not use constructor to reinitialise. This answer is worse than question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to remove the listener in `onDetach`(). The reason is the Fragment may be amid of detaching, and a UI listener may be *triggered after detached*. That will confuse most apps.

Code suggestion:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    if (gridView != null) {
       gridView.setOnItemClickListener( null );
    }
    super.onDetach();
//        this.activity = null;
}
```

Note:

- Call `setOnItemClickListener()` passing **null** as parameter. I did not find any documentation to say this but this is a known trick. Besides that, there are some listeners with custom removal methods.
- I would remove code `this.activity = null` because this may be the code that caused the crash/exception. And conceptually it's better that the Activity class set this object instead of the Fragment class.